# EF: Restriction on data types mapping

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, metadata

Is it possible to edit the error message of type of data on EF ?

For example, I've to display to the end-user that `the value entered on ID's field must be integer`.

```
public int ID { get; set; }
```

Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regular expression annotation to validate digits only

```
[RegularExpression(@"^\d+$",ErrorMessage="the value entered on ID's field must be integer")]
public int MyInt { get; set; }
```

[image]

Comment: It will not work. RegularExpression validator will be applied after binding data to int, so if there were not integer value - there will be default error message

Comment: If you change the type to a `string`, it will work. You'll have to parse it to an integer yourself though.

Comment: @KirillBestemyanov Works for me using `int` datatype

Answer (score 0):

You can use Range validator:

```
 [Range(int.MinValue, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessageResourceName = "IDMustBeInteger",
    ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof (Resources))]
```

Comment: It will not work. Range validator will be applied after binding data to int, so if there were not integer value - there will be default error message

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have two possible solutions for your problem:

1. You can write client validation to check this on client (using regexp or something else)
2. You can use custom `ModelBinder` to intercept default error.